# Plesk not starting after server reboot because of MySQL socket

Tags: mysql

I've a problem with my plesk (12.5.30) installation on a fresh Ubuntu14.04 LTS server.

I used plesk autoinstaller file downloaded from plesk official website, to install plesk.

It seems that the installation was successful, however each time after I reboot the server, plesk is not starting showing the error that:

```
ERROR: PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect():
No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). 
Please check that database server is started and accessible. (Abstract.php:69)
```

I've checked mysql service status and mysql is running. I've checked `/var/run/mysqld/` directory and there is no mysqld.sock file there.

However after restarting mysql using this command: `sudo service mysql restart`, plesk start functioning. I want plesk starts automatically after server restart without the need to restart mysql service.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I finally replaced the OS with Debian 7 and plesk is working fine successfully.